# Power management over IPMI and HP iLO2

Tags: hp-proliant, electrical-power, ipmi, ilo, ipmitool

I tried to reboot server over IPMI and the integrated service processor/BMC. It worked for IBM server with an Integrated Management Module (IMM), but failed with HP iLO2 (FW v2.05).

I used `ipmiutil.exe` for Windows so far and would be able to use `ipmitool`on a Linux machine.

Following line worked for an IBM IMM/BMC (shut down server):

```
ipmiutil reset -d -N 192.168.1.123 -U adminaccount -P adminpassword
```

Using this for a HP iLO2 I get:

```
ipmilan_open_session error, rv = -15

ireset: powering down ...
set_boot_options ccode 80, resp[0] = c2, resp[1] =  e4
ireset: IPMI_Reset error 128
ipmiutil reset, Invalid Session Handle or Empty Buffer
```

Any hints? Somebody tried this before?

Thanks, milde.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Well, for an HP ILO2 management processor, you can do this via ssh. Something like `ssh -l Administrator 192.168.1.x "power warm"` would do a warm boot of the server. I've never attempted via ipmitool, though. You can also SSH into the ILO2 and examine the command-line options:

```
</>hpiLO-> power

power: server power is currently: On

</>hpiLO-> power help

POWER    : Control server power.
power          - Display the current server power state
CLP COMMAND    - show /system1 enabledstate
power on       - Turn the server on
CLP COMMAND    - start /system1
power off      - Turn the server off
CLP COMMAND    - stop /system1
power reset    - Reset the server
CLP COMMAND    - reset /system1
power warm     - Warm boot the server
CLP COMMAND    - reset /system1 soft
```

This thread on the HP forums also addresses the issue for Linux-based systems.

http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/General/Using-ipmitool-with-iLO-2/m-p/3921246/highlight/true#M14290

Comment: ssh is working, but the syntax is different for iLO,IMM,... I'm looking for a independent command for all (in this case HP,IBM,FuSi) processors. I check OpenIPMI, mentioned in the thread you posted.

Comment: Yeah, the syntax will be different for different vendors, and may even change between hardware/firmware versions from a single vendor. You best option would be to code it up for each vendor's hardware as a subroutine, and do some discovery first in your script to see which power-on function to run.

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
ipmitool -I lanplus -U adminuser -P yourpassword -H 192.168.10.20 sensor
```

Check this link for some info:

http://www.tricksguide.com/intelligent-platform-management-interface-over-lan-on-hp-proliant-servers.html